# Symfony2 How to add required form field dynamically

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

In Form-Builder, I have a choice of fields for a `Credit Card` or `Bill Payment Type`.

Depending on what is selected, other form fields will be loaded `i.e. CC-Number or Bank Account`.

I need the CC-Number input to be a required field, if Credit Card is selected. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this [cookbook entry for the backend side](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-underlying-data),
the Javascript code needed on the client side is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that fits my needs by myself:

If a field is required it has the attribute required="required". So i did a little piece of jQuery, which removes or adds this attribute on elements that are hidden or shown.

Comment: This is just client side validation. You should not rely on this.

Comment: I'm now using a jQuery Validation Plugin and serverside validation